# Call a method passed as a prop in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, methods, react-router

i have method in my parent element, an d i passed it as a prop; like this:

```
<NavBar retrieveList={this.retrieveList}/>
```

and in my child component i can not able to call this method from another method body.

```
handleCloseModal () {
    window.$('#newHireModal').modal('hide');   /* this is working */
    console.log(this.props.retrieveList);     /* it gives method body, just to be sure props is coming here */
    this.props.retrieveList;   /*it gives "Expected an assignment or function call..." */
    this.props.retrieveList();   /*it gives "this.props.retrieveList is not a function" */
    return this.props.retrieveList;   /*it does nothing. no working, no error. */
  }
```

By the way i have got constructor and bind;

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleCloseModal = this.handleCloseModal.bind(this);
```

```
retrieveList() {
    StaffDataService.getAll()
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          staffWithBasics: response.data,
          filteredItems: response.data,
        });
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }
```

what is my wrong with this code, how can i run this parent method?

Comment: Can you share what `this.retrieveList` is when you pass it to `NavBar`? It seems like it might not be a function.

Comment: ```retrieveList() {
    StaffDataService.getAll()
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          staffWithBasics: response.data,
          filteredItems: response.data,
        });
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }```

Comment: have you tried: `<NavBar retrieveList={this.retrieveList.bind(this)}/>` and then calling it in your method body by using `this.props.retrieveList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the `this` in the component that receives the delegate is different from the `this` used in the function. You will have to bind it when passing it down.

```js
<NavBar retrieveList={this.retrieveList.bind(this)}/>
```

And then you can call it in your function body as follows.

```js
this.props.retrieveList();
```

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot. actually i was already bind `retrieveList` in my parent component, but when sending as a "prop", add `.bind` solved problem.