# How to call props arrow function in react

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions

I'm a beginner react developer.
I have a component with `UpdateUsers` props function that called in Main Component:

Main Component:

```
UpdateUsers = () => {...}
 render(){
   return(
     <User UpdateUsers = {this.UpdateUsers} />
  )}
```

in User Component, I can't call the `UpdateUsers` function correctly.

User:

```
addUser = () => {
   //do some other things
   //code for adding user
   this.props.UpdateUsers();
}

render(){
   return(
     //do some other things
     <Button onClick={this.addUser}>ADD<Button/>
  )}
```

The `this.props.UpdateUsers();` that I've called in `addUser` doesn't work. If I call this in the button `OnCkick` it works. but calling it in a`ddUser` dose not work correctly .

How can I call `this.props.UpdateUsers` in the `addUser` function?

Comment: what's the issue with your current code?

Comment: The `this.props.UpdateUsers();` that I call in `addUser` doesn't work.
If I call this in the button `OnCkick` it works. but calling it in `addUser` dose not work correctly

Comment: Did you call `super(props);` in **User** component's constructor?

Comment: please share the whole User component code and the error if it exists

Comment: What do you mean by **dose not work correctly**? Please share the exact error details if any.

Comment: I called `super(props);` in the constructor.
My code has no error. It just doesn't work in the first call.
I mean when I click on the button, first time just add user without UpdateUser. in the second time that I add User, this code add User2 and run the previous UpdateUser.

Comment: @ZahraTalebi can you show the code inside of `UpdateUsers` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that some functions need time to run.

in this case, adding user before `UpdateUsers` is time consuming function. the reason that `UpdateUsers` couldn't show new user (that I added) in the list, and show that after adding another user, was time issue!

We could resolve this problem by defining `async` functions like this:

in User Component:

```
addUser = async () => {
   //do some other things
   await //code for adding user
   this.props.UpdateUsers();
}

render(){
   return(
     //do some other things
     <Button onClick={this.addUser}>ADD<Button/>
  )}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's the problem because I can't see the whole code of `Main` and `User` components. It would be helpful if you tell me more about your problem.

In case `UpdateUsers`  was not called after you click a button, the code below solves it, but if it was called and didn't something you expected, then I need o know more about your issue.

```
class User extends Component {
  addUser = () => {
    this.props.addUser();
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.addUser}>
        Add user
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Main extends Component {
  addUser = () => {
    // do something here 
  }

  render() {
    return <User addUser={this.addUser} />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

look at this solution;
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63302124/call-a-method-passed-as-a-prop-in-react`
you can use .bind when you are sending method as props.